# The axes grid was not displayed in the Paraview Python script

Tags: python, paraview

I have obtained a wind simulation result and wish to slice it at seven different heights in the z-direction to calculate wind speed ratios and save each screenshot. However, I am encountering a problem where the axes grid only appears in the first loop, as in the second loop, only the wind speed ratios are displayed. Here is what I had tried.

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
import numpy as np

#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

# get the material library
materialLibrary1 = GetMaterialLibrary()

# Create a new 'Render View'
renderView1 = CreateView('RenderView')
renderView1.ViewSize = [1280, 720]
renderView1.AxesGrid = 'GridAxes3DActor'
renderView1.OrientationAxesVisibility = 0
renderView1.CenterOfRotation = [1000.0, 1145.0, 10.0]
renderView1.StereoType = 'Crystal Eyes'
renderView1.CameraPosition = [1000.0, 1145.0, 4864.234146297973]
renderView1.CameraFocalPoint = [1000.0, 1145.0, 10.0]
renderView1.CameraViewUp = [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
renderView1.CameraFocalDisk = 1.0
renderView1.CameraParallelScale = 1520.2055782031587
renderView1.BackEnd = 'OSPRay raycaster'
renderView1.OSPRayMaterialLibrary = materialLibrary1

SetActiveView(None)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# setup view layouts
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

# create new layout object 'Layout #1'
layout1 = CreateLayout(name='Layout #1')
layout1.AssignView(0, renderView1)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# restore active view
SetActiveView(renderView1)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------


# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# setup the inlet velocity profile
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
u_ref = 30
z_ref = 10
z0 = 0.0002
kappa = 0.41
u_star = u_ref*kappa/np.log((z_ref+z0)/z0)
height = [5,10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
inlet_speed = [u_star / kappa * np.log((h + z0) / z0) for h in height]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# setup the data processing pipelines
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

# create a new 'OpenFOAMReader'
runfoam = OpenFOAMReader(FileName='run.foam')
runfoam.MeshRegions = ['internalMesh']
runfoam.CellArrays = ['U', 'epsilon', 'k', 'nut', 'p']


# Set active time step to the second timestep
reader = GetActiveSource()
view = GetActiveView()
times = reader.TimestepValues
view.ViewTime = times[1]

# create a new 'Slice'
slice1 = Slice(Input=runfoam)
slice1.SliceType = 'Plane'
slice1.HyperTreeGridSlicer = 'Plane'
slice1.SliceOffsetValues = [0.0]

for ii in range(len(height)):

    # init the 'Plane' selected for 'SliceType'
    slice1.SliceType.Origin = [1000.0, 1145.0, height[ii]]
    slice1.SliceType.Normal = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    renderView1.AxesGrid = 'GridAxes3DActor'  # add this line to show axes grid
    renderView1.Update()

    # init the 'Plane' selected for 'HyperTreeGridSlicer'
    slice1.HyperTreeGridSlicer.Origin = [1000.0, 1145.0, 107.32312601804733]

    # create a new 'Calculator'
    calculator1 = Calculator(Input=slice1)
    calculator1.ResultArrayName = 'Uratio'
    calculator1.Function = 'U/'+str(inlet_speed[ii])
    renderView1.Update()
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
    # setup the visualization in view 'renderView1'
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------

    # show data from calculator1
    calculator1Display = Show(calculator1, renderView1, 'GeometryRepresentation')

    # get color transfer function/color map for 'Uratio'
    uratioLUT = GetColorTransferFunction('Uratio')
    uratioLUT.AutomaticRescaleRangeMode = 'Never'
    uratioLUT.RGBPoints = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5625, 0.1555554, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5111112999999999, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6888888999999999, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.8666664999999999, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.2222224, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0]
    uratioLUT.ColorSpace = 'RGB'
    uratioLUT.NumberOfTableValues = 14
    uratioLUT.ScalarRangeInitialized = 1.0
    
    
    # trace defaults for the display properties.
    calculator1Display.Representation = 'Surface'
    calculator1Display.ColorArrayName = ['POINTS', 'Uratio']
    calculator1Display.LookupTable = uratioLUT
    calculator1Display.OSPRayScaleArray = 'p'
    calculator1Display.OSPRayScaleFunction = 'PiecewiseFunction'
    calculator1Display.SelectOrientationVectors = 'Uratio'
    calculator1Display.ScaleFactor = 229.0
    calculator1Display.SelectScaleArray = 'p'
    calculator1Display.GlyphType = 'Arrow'
    calculator1Display.GlyphTableIndexArray = 'p'
    calculator1Display.GaussianRadius = 11.450000000000001
    calculator1Display.SetScaleArray = ['POINTS', 'p']
    calculator1Display.ScaleTransferFunction = 'PiecewiseFunction'
    calculator1Display.OpacityArray = ['POINTS', 'p']
    calculator1Display.OpacityTransferFunction = 'PiecewiseFunction'
    calculator1Display.DataAxesGrid = 'GridAxesRepresentation'
    calculator1Display.PolarAxes = 'PolarAxesRepresentation'

    # init the 'PiecewiseFunction' selected for 'ScaleTransferFunction'
    calculator1Display.ScaleTransferFunction.Points = [-1396.27392578125, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 570.5612182617188, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0]

    # init the 'PiecewiseFunction' selected for 'OpacityTransferFunction'
    calculator1Display.OpacityTransferFunction.Points = [-1396.27392578125, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 570.5612182617188, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0]

    # init the 'GridAxes3DActor' selected for 'AxesGrid'
    
    renderView1.AxesGrid.XTitle = ''
    renderView1.AxesGrid.YTitle = ''
    renderView1.AxesGrid.ZTitle = ''
    renderView1.AxesGrid.XTitleBold = 1
    renderView1.AxesGrid.XTitleFontSize = 28
    renderView1.AxesGrid.YTitleBold = 1
    renderView1.AxesGrid.YTitleFontSize = 28
    renderView1.AxesGrid.AxesToLabel = 3
    renderView1.AxesGrid.XLabelBold = 1
    renderView1.AxesGrid.XLabelFontSize = 28
    renderView1.AxesGrid.YLabelBold = 1
    renderView1.AxesGrid.YLabelFontSize = 28
    renderView1.AxesGrid.ZLabelBold = 1
    
    renderView1.Update()
    # setup the color legend parameters for each legend in this view

    # get color legend/bar for uratioLUT in view renderView1
    uratioLUTColorBar = GetScalarBar(uratioLUT, renderView1)
    uratioLUTColorBar.WindowLocation = 'AnyLocation'
    uratioLUTColorBar.Position = [0.7813682909604519, 0.12386300027987682]
    uratioLUTColorBar.Title = 'U/Uinlet'
    uratioLUTColorBar.ComponentTitle = ''
    uratioLUTColorBar.TitleBold = 1
    uratioLUTColorBar.TitleFontSize = 24
    uratioLUTColorBar.LabelBold = 1
    uratioLUTColorBar.LabelFontSize = 24
    uratioLUTColorBar.RangeLabelFormat = '%-#6.1f'
    uratioLUTColorBar.ScalarBarLength = 0.4345340050377833

    # set color bar visibility
    uratioLUTColorBar.Visibility = 1

    # show color legend
    calculator1Display.SetScalarBarVisibility(renderView1, True)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------
    # setup color maps and opacity mapes used in the visualization
    # note: the Get..() functions create a new object, if needed
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------

    # get opacity transfer function/opacity map for 'Uratio'
    uratioPWF = GetOpacityTransferFunction('Uratio')
    uratioPWF.Points = [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.4, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0]
    uratioPWF.ScalarRangeInitialized = 1

    # save screenshot
    SaveScreenshot('test'+str(height[ii])+'.tiff', renderView1, ImageResolution=[2560, 1440], 
        # TIFF options
        Compression='None')
```

Comment: Not sure it will solve your problem, but you should put quite all code outside of the `for` loop (specially the calculator creation and display configuration).

The concept of ParaView is to build a pipeline (see [doc](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/filteringData.html)), i.e. a list of connected filters. Then modify a parameter (for instance in a loop) and call update to retrigger the whole execution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion on my question - I really appreciate your help! Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, putting my code outside the for loop didn't work for me. But I wanted to let you know that I ended up using Matlab to output my figures and make more modifications. Thanks again for your assistance.